# ViewPager ViewPager.PageTransformer causes unusual click

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

Here is my scenario. In a ViewPager i have two fragment. In second Fragment i have a list of item & each item is clickable. I used `ViewPager.PageTransformer` to animate my ViewPager to go from one fragment to another.

I used this : `vPager.setPageTransformer(true, new FlipPageViewTransformer());`

where `FlipPageViewTransformer` is taken from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager) `Depth page transformer`.

Now the problem is when I am in first fragment & when i click on it, it takes the second fragment's item click though i am still in first fragment. It is such a weird problem.

Comment: try`vPager.setPageTransformer(false, new FlipPageViewTransformer());` First parameter decides the drawing order of pages, so if your front page was drawn first then whatever is drawn after will take focus and click events which will create this unusual effect that you are seeing.

Comment: i did it long time ago. you may try by setting first parameter false as @wajeeh said. If works then let me know

Comment: had same problem with os 4.1.1 when using mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());, on current page clicking on view item but the viewitem on idle page's onclickHandler got called.

Comment: @Sayem have you solved it?